# Execute .on() function automatically after page load

Tags: jquery

I use `$("#container").on("click", contentEffects);` to make some jquery code work again after ajax call. However, I hope the `.on()` function can be executed immediately and automatically after page load, and without the `click` event. Is that possible?

Please take a look at my site and the javascript file:

http://peters-playground.com/blog.html

https://github.com/P233/p233.github.com/blob/master/js/script.js#L30-L78

When new post is loaded by ajax, I have to click on the post content to enable javascript and I also need to click button twice to make it work. That is really annoying. How can I avoid this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run it in your chain:

```javascript
// Anonymouse function passed into $ will be invoked
// When the document has loaded
$(function () {

    // Immediately after binding the click handler
    // We invoke the click event on #container
    $("#container").on("click", contentEffects).click();

});
```

What is sounds like you should consider though is *event-delegation*, and binding events to the nearest static ancestor element that is present when the page loads. For instance, suppose we have a list of items populated dynamically by AJAX:

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>First item on load.</li>
    <!-- More items will be loaded
         via AJAX later on --->
</ul>
```

You might want the list items to do something when you click on them, so you would probably bind handler to their click event:

```
$("#items li").on("click", function () {
    alert( $(this).html() );
});
```

This works for any list items *already on the page*, but as you are experiencing, new items won't have this bound to them, so after your AJAX you will have to re-bind it to all new list items.

Instead of doing this, we can bind to the `ul` element, which is always present, and simply listen for events that originated from `li` elements:

```
$("#items").on("click", "li", function () {
    alert( $(this).html() );
});
```

Now our event never needs to be re-bound, since `#items` is loaded with the page, and never goes anywhere. Any click event that bubbles up to this element from a nested list item (whether it was loaded via AJAX or not) will be captured and handled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I have two small questions, can I use other events rather then click? Because if I click on the post content, Disqus will reload again. And, if people visit this site through a link like domain.com#/post_name.html, the jquery code still not works. Sorry, this maybe stupid. But I am not confident to use jquery, I have already done many research to write this site, this is the only problem I cannot handle :(

Comment: @Peiwen You can use delegation with any event that bubbles. You can see the documentation for `$.on` for a list. I'm not sure what you mean by "disqus will reload again" if people click in a certain area; it may be necessary to `stopPropagation` from clicks coming from a particular element. I would need more information about your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code https://github.com/P233/p233.github.com/blob/master/js/script.js#L102, am I doing wrong? Can you please visit the site again? Cheers.

Comment: @Peiwen Why are you putting these functions inside `$('.cate1, #about').click()`? You are setting all of this up within the click handler of `.cate1` and `#about`.

Comment: I hope both `.cate1` links and the `#about` link can trigger ajax call, and actually the `#about` link will come back to index page.

Comment: @Peiwen That's fine, but you are binding other click events from within the `.cate1|#about` click event. That is why you have to click multiple times.

Comment: I created an empty div named `#tirgger` instead of `#container`. This problem is solved. But there is another little problem, if `currentEffects` is executed at the very beginning of page load ([line101](https://github.com/P233/p233.github.com/blob/master/js/script.js#L101)), ajax will not work. Would you mind to take a look at this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to execute .on function after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#container").on("click", function() {
         //Your Code
         });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when you answer a question please try to also include an explanation of *why* your code works, and links to relevant documentation as well.